# Why do I get KeyError: 'Target_Variable' when I perform Mean Squared Error for XGBoost?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xgboost, mean-square-error

I'm performing XGBoost on my flight delay datasets . I executed and trained the dataset however when I tried to find the mean squared error test I got the above error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_late.drop(['DELAY_YN','ARR_DELAY'],axis=1), 
                                                    df_late['ARR_DELAY'], test_size=0.30, random_state=101)

print('Training...')
xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators= 2000, max_depth= 5,learning_rate =0.1)
xg_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

print('Predicting on test set...')
predictions = xg_reg.predict(X_test)

y_test['predicted']=[np.exp(p) for p in predictions]

from sklearn import metrics
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted']))
print('MSE:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted']))
print('RMSE:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted'])))
```

I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-b9b5e43dd55b> in <module>
      2 
      3 from sklearn import metrics
----> 4 print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted']))
      5 print('MSE:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted']))
      6 print('RMSE:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test['ARR_DELAY'],y_test['predicted'])))

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4318         try:
   4319             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4320                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4321         except KeyError as e1:
   4322             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'ARR_DELAY'
```

What might be the problem ? I'm very new to Data Science hence any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start by checking `y_test.columns` to make sure that the column you're trying to use is called the same in the dataframe. `KeyError` means it can't find the key you're trying to index with.

Answer (score 0):

After train/test split here:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_late.drop(['DELAY_YN','ARR_DELAY'],axis=1), 
                                                    df_late['ARR_DELAY'], test_size=0.30, random_state=101)
```

`y_test` is in fact not a DataFrame but a Series, consists of a single column. So `y_test['predicted']=[np.exp(p) for p in predictions]` is not really what you want. Instead, I would suggest keep predictions in a separate array or a Series:

```py
predictions = xg_reg.predict(X_test)

predictions = np.exp(predictions)

from sklearn import metrics
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions))
...
```